# Falla con enlace de Selenium ide

Tags: selenium, test, testing, selenium-ide

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Como ven en la imagen esta en primer lugar el resultado de la Selenium en la fila 18, en segundo lugar está el enlace y por último el código, como ven en este el span tiene una class acceshide con la palabra foro
Capáz que tendría que usar otro comando en lugar de verify text, cual me recomiendan?